# (Re)name factor levels (or include variable name) in ggplot2 facet_ call

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plyr

One pattern I do a lot is to facet plots on cuts of numeric values. facet_wrap in ggplot2 doesn't allow you to call a function from within, so you have to create a temporary factor variable. This is okay using mutate from dplyr. The advantage of this is that you can play around doing EDA and varying the number of quantiles, or changing to set cut points etc. and view the changes in one line. The downside is that the facets are only labelled by the factor level; you have to know, for example, that it's a temperature. This isn't too bad for yourself, but even I get confused if I'm doing a facet_grid on two such variables and have to remember which is which. So, it's really nice to be able to relabel the facets by including a meaningful name.

The key points of this problem is that the levels will change as you change the number of quantiles etc.; you don't know what they are in advance. You could use the base levels() function, but that means augmenting the data frame with the cut variable, then calling levels(), then passing this augmented data frame to ggplot().

So, using plyr::mapvalues, we can wrap all this into a dplyr::mutate, but the required arguments for mapvalues() makes it quite clunky. Having to retype "Temp.f" many times is not very "dplyr"!

Is there a neater way of renaming such factor levels "on the fly"? I hope this description is clear enough and the code example below helps.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
df <- data.frame(Temp = seq(-100, 100, length.out = 1000), y = rnorm(1000))

# facet_wrap doesn't allow functions so have to create new, temporary factor
# variable Temp.f
ggplot(df %>% mutate(Temp.f = cut2(Temp, g = 4))) + geom_histogram(aes(x = y)) + facet_wrap(~Temp.f)
# fine, but facet headers aren't very clear,
# we want to highlight that they are temperature
ggplot(df %>% mutate(Temp.f = paste0("Temp: ", cut2(Temp, g = 4)))) + geom_histogram(aes(x = y)) + facet_wrap(~Temp.f)
# use of paste0 is undesirable because it creates a character vector and
# facet_wrap then recodes the levels in the wrong numerical order

# This has the desired effect, but is very long!
ggplot(df %>% mutate(Temp.f = cut2(Temp, g = 4), Temp.f = mapvalues(Temp.f, levels(Temp.f), paste0("Temp: ", levels(Temp.f))))) + geom_histogram(aes(x = y)) + facet_wrap(~Temp.f)
```

Comment: Rename the factors prior to plotting with `df$newFactor <- factor(df$oldFactor, levels=c(...))` or use `levels(df$oldFactor) <- c(...)`

Comment: As an alternative to `cut2` you can also use the `cut` function from base R with the `labels` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this from within `facet_wrap` using a custom labeller function, like so:

```
myLabeller <- function(x){
  lapply(x,function(y){
    paste("Temp:", y)
  })
}

ggplot(df %>% mutate(Temp.f = cut2(Temp, g = 4))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = y)) +
  facet_wrap(~Temp.f
             , labeller = myLabeller)
```

That labeller is clunky, but at least an example. You could write one for each variable that you are going to use (e.g. `tempLabeller`, `yLabeller`, etc).

[image]

A slight tweak makes this even better: it automatically uses the name of the thing you are facetting on:

```
betterLabeller <- function(x){
  lapply(names(x),function(y){
    paste0(y,": ", x[[y]])
  })
}

ggplot(df %>% mutate(Temp.f = cut2(Temp, g = 4))) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = y)) +
  facet_wrap(~Temp.f
             , labeller = betterLabeller)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, with thanks to Mark Peterson for pointing me towards the labeller argument/function, the exact answer I'm happy with is:

```
ggplot(df %>% mutate(Temp.f = cut2(Temp, g = 4))) + geom_histogram(aes(x = y)) + facet_wrap(~Temp.f, labeller = labeller(Temp.f = label_both))
```

I'm a fan of lazy and "label_both" means I can simply create a meaningful temporary (or overwrite the original) variable column and both the name and the value are given. Rolling your own labeller function is more powerful, but using label_both is a good, easy option.